# Is it possible to run PHP on a .js page?

Tags: php, javascript, header

So far no luck experimenting. I need to run a php function to check a header (from my understanding not possible through js), but the page needs to be a .js as it is being access by other pages as  and it was requested to keep it like that.

I won't be to shaken up if I can't run PHP directly in the page though, theres always other ways.  I just wanted to see if there was a simple way.

EDIT: This is all run on a server. Sorry, I didn't clarify that. (not this big of a noob mistake)

Comment: any file can be passed through the servers php engine. extension is meaningless.

Comment: @Calvin There is no way to run php in a browser as far as I know, however you can run php server side and output javascript from the php script. Effectively you'd be dynamically changing your javascript via php on the server before sending it to the browser for execution.

Comment: @hafichuk thanks, but it is being run on a server. Sorry, I didn't clarify that.

Comment: In general, 1) "php == run at web server" => 2) "HTML+Javascript+CSS => sent from web server to client browser" => 3) "javascript == run  at client browser"

Comment: Sorry. I guess I needed to clarify further. The php is run on the server. The javascript is all being processed client side.

Comment: just rename the file extension from js to php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit .htaccess file to

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .js

<FilesMatch "\.(js|php)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Then you can run PHP in a js file.

Comment: thanks. I was hoping to find a way to not have to modify the .htaccess for this but I'm thinking that might end up being my route.

Comment: @Calvin That's not possible really, as you have to tell the server to process the .js file as PHP somehow. If not in .htaccess, then in the main httpd.conf is the other choice.

Comment: Just beware that this will run *all* of your js files through the php interpreter. If you only have a single file that you need to do this for, then I'd suggest only matching for that one file.

Comment: But that's just lying to the server: telling it a .js file should be treated as a .php file.  Why not just call it a .php file?  And what happens if somebody expects to find Javascript commands in this mis-named .js file?  It's just a Really, Really Bad Idea...

Comment: @hafichuk how would I go about changing it for just a single file? That was my main concern and the reason I didn't go that route to start with.

Comment: The `FilesMatch` value is just a regex stating `if the end of the file is js or php`. You just need to change this to `"myfile.js$"`.

Comment: +1 to @paulsm4 comment as well. Since your hands are tied and can't rename the file, be nice to the next guy and make sure you comment this change in both the js and the .htaccess file.

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately renaming it isn't possible for me at the time but I will make sure to make great comments in htaccess and in the .js file explaining it all.  Also it is mainly javascript, just 1 php command needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Apache, adding the line `AddType application/x-httpd-php .js` in your `.htaccess` file will set `.js` files to be processed as PHP.